# SlidingMenu Fragment Switch Listener Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, fragment, onclicklistener, android-sliding

I'm calling on this acitvity as my main laucher this activity extends the SlidingActivity from this library https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu.  When it creates a behindcontentview for the slidingmenu I use with a fragment.  In this main activity I creating a custom view for a calendar  there are icons that are drawed in this custom view. I want to toggle these icons so I'm using switches in the sliding menu fragment view but I'm getting a null pointer exception which log cat saids its happens in the listner when i toggle in the fragment where the switch is.  So my code to clears the  icons on a calendar that is made using the custom view in the main activty and  does work with I use the code in the main activity but not within the toggle listner OnCheckedChangeListener.

Heres Mainactivity that calls on the slide menu and fragment to fill the slide menu

```
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFrag = new ColorFragment();
    t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
    t.commit();

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    //sm.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW);



    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //redrawtest();
   // setListener();
```

Heres my xml for this main activity.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.projects.shiftcalendar.CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/view_month_calendar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</com.projects.shiftcalendar.CalendarView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_menu_toggle, null );

}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Switch d = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.monitored_switch1);
    d.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {



    if(isChecked){

        cv.redrawCalendarClearSymbol();



    }
    else {

        cv.redrawCalendarClearSymbol();


      }



  }


}
```

Comment: Can you give me full code, actually i have problem for sliding menu with different fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I'm getting a null pointer exception which log cat saids its happens in the listner when i toggle in the fragment where the switch is (...) [doesn't work within the toggle listner OnCheckedChangeListener.

Based on your description, the NullPointerException happens when you call:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
     //...        
    cv.redrawCalendarClearSymbol();
```

It seems like `cv` is null. One possible reason for the NPE is that `cv` hasn't been instantiated when the Fragment was created. Assuming `cv` is part of your fragment's layout, you can assign a reference to 'cv' in `onCreateView()`:

```
YourCustomType cv;//field

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_menu_toggle, null);
    cv = (YourCustomType)vg.findViewById(R.id.yourIdForCVInTheFragmentLayout);
    return vg;
}
```